# GRUB2 не отображает Windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ос, dual-boot

В общем, решил я установить себе Ubuntu на компьютер, подготовился, прочитал инструкции с десяток раз, предварительно выделил место и тд.
Однако, после запуска установщика Ubuntu, он вел себя не так как описывалось в инструкции с официального сайта : в частности, не спрашивал в какой раздел диска он будет устанавливаться.
При установке выбрал пункт "установить рядом с windows" и прочие приглашения типа "хотите ли вы запускать другие OS в дальнейшем" отвечал положительно.
В итоге, после установки дистрибутива, меню загрузчика GRUB не содержит пункта Windows, что лично для меня оказалось как минимум неприятно. Почитал несколько форумов, везде предлагаются инструкции восстановления загрузчика Windows путем манипуляций с установочным диском. Меня такая перспектива не сильно устраивает так как доступа к установочному диску Windows у меня на данный момент нет.
Еще были разговоры о том что нужно править конфигурационный файл GRUB, но толковых инструкций на эту тему найти не удалось.

К слову, все виндовсовские каталоги и разбиения на томы остались, включая всё содержимое, что явно свидетельствует о том что ось не была удалена (я надеюсь).

Жду ответов, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Неплохо бы последний дополненный абзац оформить как ответ…

Comment: @mymedia , спасибо что напомнили, я тут совсем новенький

Comment: Для указания решения проблемы [отметьте свой ответ галочкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) (когда она станет доступной через два дня), после чего уберите приписку «решён» из заголовка вопроса.

Comment: Не нужно, добавлять (решен) к заголовку вопроса, отметьте ответ верным, поставив слева от него галочку

Comment: @Arhad, никак я первый ничего не напишу ;)

Comment: @Flippy, у меня с ответами похожая бывает ерунда.

Comment: после добавления собственного ответа его можно отметить галочкой только через два дня, так что как только так сразу, а пока пусть в тайтле висит что вопрос решен, но спасибо что обращаете внимание =)

Comment: Уже не висит :)

Comment: @Flippy да, я заметил х)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решение найдено. После пары часов поиска по форумам наткнулся на команду:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Сразу же после ее выполнения получил сообщение что граб нашел загрузчик винды, перезагрузился и нашел заветный пункт в меню граба =)